# Why is the plot.TukeyHSD method not visible?

Tags: r, function, plot

In `help(TukeyHSD)`, it is clearly indicated that a `print` and `plot` method is available:

> There are print and plot methods for class "TukeyHSD"

However, typing `plot.TukeyHSD` leads to "object not found" error.

1) If I want to see the code of `plot.TukeyHSD` to do some monkey patching, how to do it?

2) Why is `plot.TukeyHSD` not visible? I hope that this puzzle will lead to some deeper understanding of R for me.

Comment: If you type `methods(plot)` you should see "plot.TukeyHSD*" in the list of methods. To see the code of a non-exported function use `getAnywhere`.

Comment: Thanks! `methods(plot)` shows which method is visible or not even. Is there any reasoning / best practice behind which method is exported or not?

Comment: I honestly am not aware of the standards that authors use in deciding whether to export functions or not.